# JSF Supported Languages from ManagedBeans

Tags: jsf, localization, jsf-2

I've defined my supported languages in `faces-config.xml` as follow:

```
<locale-config>
  <default-locale>fa</default-locale>
  <supported-locale>fa</supported-locale>
  <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

How can I access supported locales in a `ManagedBean` ? e.g. to populate a list with corresponding items.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getSupportedLocales()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getSupportedLocales%28%29)